# Making Tank_Auth user profiles codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I have set up on my test server codeigniter with tank_auth but I would like to know how I would be best to make sure when new user is registered make sure some selected data goes in to the database table user_profiles i.e. Country, Website,

I am going to be creating a users profile page dashboard/account/

If there are any links on this subject please give them to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just let people make a basic account: email, password (, username) and after they are registered and logged in let them add this extra info (e.g.: gender, website, county, etc.) on their profile page.

That's the way way i do it and i think it works fine.